Send an email using AWS GLue
I have a job making an ETL with GLue, i need to send on the final of this script a email with some "data quality", transforming the DataFrame spark to pandas and using matplotlib to plot some graphs. I try to use AWS SES but i don't think that i had access to use, so i need some help to send this email, what lib i can use for this?
Another problem is, how to save this graph in a image extension and put on th body of this email?
I try to use AWS SES for emailing, but an error in create identity doens't let me do it. So i'm lost :(
The error tell's me that i don't have permission access to execute this action.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

More than a question, this seems an entire project tbh :D.
The first question you should ask yourself is: "Do you really want to use glue for this?"
Keep in mind that transforming a spark dataframe into a pandas one could already be an issue if you are dealing with a huge amount of data. And if you are not, well why are you using spark in the first place?
Aside from that, I will divide my answer in three parts.
1 The "ugly" but fast way.
You should be able to use SES to send out emails, although mind that for sending emails to not verified users you will need to do an explicit request to AWS.
To do so you will need to import boto3 in your script Here there is a so topic that explains you how.
Then you can use the SES SDK to send out an email with whatever html body you want.
2 The "better" way.
You will still need the boto3 sdk for this. The idea, though, is not to send out directly the email from aws glue but rather saving the graph to S3 and then use an AWS Lambda to send out the email.
You could think that this could cost you more, but given the running cost of an AWS Glue Job i wouldn't bet on it.
To do so you will need:

A S3 bucket
An AWS Lambda that will use boto3 with the SES SDK to send out the email (just like in point 1)
A S3 notification that will trigger the lambda every time a new graph is uploaded

This would give your solution a little more flexibility, but it will be a little more complex to achieve.
3 The way I would do it
First. If the amount of data is not that huge, consider using an AWS Lambda with pandas or an AWS Batch job based on Fargate. Directly use pandas and skip the spark part.
If you're dealing with a lot of data though, you could still transform and filter out all the data that is not needed, eventually ending up with only the data strictly needed for the graph.
You will then store this result directly as a CSV or parquet file to S3 directly with spark (without having to import boto3).
From there, you will be able to do basically the same process described at point 2, but using pandas and boto3 in the AWS lambda that will in order:

pick up the final file in a pandas dataframe
produce the graph
send the email

Final considerations
Mind that sending an image over email is not so trivial. You can find another discussion about that here.
If you don't give us more detail about the error you are getting on the identity policy I guess it would be nearly impossible for us to help you with that. Either way, you can find plenty of examples online on how to do so, I will drop a couple of resources down below.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/python_3_ses_code_examples.html
https://codelovingyogi.medium.com/sending-emails-using-aws-simple-email-service-ses-220de9db4fc8
Access Denied while sending email from AWS SES in Lambda function

Hope this has been of any help. Good luck out there :)
